# Merging two queries that are the same BUT their GROUP BY?

Tags: sql, merge, group-by, equals

So as the title implies, I have the same exact structure for two queries but I just need to change the grouping.  I know I can do a union, however, to narrow the script, is there a way to associate both grouping in one query?  For example:

```
SELECT shtuff FROM report_tickets WHERE something = something GROUP BY companies
```

//Query two

```
SELECT shtuff FROM report_tickets WHERE something = something GROUP BY ticket_id
```

Can I do?:

```
SELECT * FROM report_tickets WHERE something = something GROUP BY companies AND ticket_id
```

I know this doesn't work but in concept.  Have the query take in account both groupings?  ^^

I would need to add the following to line 30 from the linked code below, this may determine if it can work or not.

```
SUM(IF(ROUND((SELECT difference)) < 1, 1, 0)) AS zero_to_one,
SUM(IF(ROUND((SELECT difference)) BETWEEN 1 AND 8, 1, 0)) AS one_to_eight,
SUM(IF(ROUND((SELECT difference)) BETWEEN 8 AND 24, 1, 0)) AS eight_to_twentyfour,
SUM(IF(ROUND((SELECT difference)) > 24, 1, 0)) AS over_twentyfour,
```

Comment: If you are actually doing a `select * ... group by` then you're doing it wrong.

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Fix your syntax . . . `select *` with `group by` doesn't make sense.  (3) Sample data and desired results can explain what you want to do.

Comment: Ok, this is my first question so I put my query in codeshare.io.  It's found here https://codeshare.io/aVybR5

Comment: My goal is to have it so I group response times to tickets (grouped with job_tickets.TID) and then I will need to group the amount of comments tickets have (grouped by CID).

Comment: You do not need group by, just use order by.  You could do something like Where something = something, Order by companies, ticket_id

If you wanted a COUNT or SUM of Ticket_ID you could then have a use for Group By

Comment: Okay, does my edit effect this, because I need the the sum of the time difference as well.  To clarify, I'm categorizing two columns, the difference (seen above) and the job_tickets.#ofComments.  Both need a separate GROUP BY to give me the right results